# Bcrypt->verify always return false

Tags: php, zend-framework, bcrypt

i don't get why my verify function always return me False. I didn't forget to put this "use Zend\Crypt\Password\Bcrypt;"

```
$form = new UtilisateurPasswordForm($idUtilisateur);
 $pass = new UtilisateurPassword();

if ($request->isPost()) {

     $form->setInputFilter($pass->getInputFilter());
     $form->setData($request->getPost());

     if ($form->isValid()) {
          $pass->exchangeArray($form->getData());

          $bcrypt      = new Bcrypt(['cost' => 14]);
          $mdp_old  = $bcrypt->create($pass->{'mdp_old'});

          $result = $this->getServiceLocator()
                  ->get('RestService')
                   ->call('inblue/utilisateur/' . $idUtilisateur);

          $mdp = $result->offsetGet('motDePasse');

          if($bcrypt->verify($mdp, $mdp_old)){
                var_dump('OH YEAH');
          }else{
                var_dump('ECHEC');
          }
     }
}
```

This is my sample from Zend where i use the bcrypt function. I don't think zend is a trouble in this case, i put some var_dump to see variables and $mdp_old is a hash and $mpd too. $mdp comes from a WebService call, and i got it right. But when i verified them, it return false and i'm sure i type the right password (i var_dump it too).

Thanks !

Edit : My bad, when using verify, we just need to instanciate $bcrypt then only put the string 
Instead of this $bcrypt->verify($mdp, $mdp_old), 
i should use $bcrypt->verify($pass->{'mdp_old'}, $mdp) 
and it's working !!